# Printing how many features satisfy a QgsFeatureRequest (QGIS 3)

Tags: pyqgis, qgsfeaturerequest

I have a QgsFeatureRequest() that filter all the features by an attribute. 
Is there any python function that could tell me how many features were filtered?
I know I could create a list with this features and then count them. But I want a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a quite short way:

```
vlayer.selectByExpression("here comes your expression")
vlayer.selectedFeatureCount()
```

If you stick to QgsFeatureRequest(), then you have to use a counter (I guess).
After vlayer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest("here comes your expression")), you will have a QgsFeatureIterator, which does not have method like featureCount().

https://qgis.org/api/classQgsFeatureIterator.html